# Why are the contents in JSON not showing in HTML?

Tags: json, angularjs, html

The following are my HTML, AngularJS, JSON codes

index.html

```
<! DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='styles/photostyle.css' />

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script src="app/app.js"></script>
        <title>My Photography</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="photoPage">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="header">
                <p id="title">My Photography</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="photoNo" ng-repeat="photo in photos">
                        <photo-infos info="photo"></photo-infos>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("photoPage", []);

app.controller("MainController", ['$scope', 'photos', function($scope, photos) {
        photos.success(function(data) {
            $scope.photos=data;
        });
    }])

    .directive('photoInfos', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                info: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'photoInfos.html'
        };
    })

    .factory("photos", ["$http", function($http) {
        return $http.get('addonFiles/photoInfo.json')
        .success( function(data) {
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            return err;
        });
    }]);
```

photoInfo.json

```
[
    {
        "name": "shot 01",
        "date": 20150321075416,
        "photoUrl": "photos/01.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "shot 02",
        "date": 20150527111604,
        "photoUrl": "photos/02.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "shot 03",
        "date": 20150626113654,
        "photoUrl": "photos/03.jpg"
    }
]
```

photoInfos.html

```
<div class="photo-container">
    <img class="photo-responsive" ng-src="{{ info.photoUrl }}"/>
<h3>{{ info.name }}</h3>
<p class="photoDate">{{ info.date }}</p>
```

The files are kept in the correct places as they should be. But my output comes out with just the div in **id="header"** and not the photos whose information is in JSON file.

why is the data in JSON not showing in the output??

Comment: first of all correct your angular link from  `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>` to `<script src="https//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>`

Comment: The photoInfos directive is referencing a template file named photoInfos.html. Do you have it?

Comment: This is too much of a code... we do not need to see your css in order to help you with ajax problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plunker with a solution:
http://plnkr.co/edit/pJBMtDkSx8gcGqPY4AyS?p=preview

Basically, I added the following template

```
  <li>{{info.name}}</li>
```

And changed the directive:

```
.directive('photoInfos', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            info: '=info'
        },
        templateUrl: 'photoInfos.html'
    };
})
```